# Is there a way to use Leaflet as a GPS tracker?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to build a map with a realtime GPS-tracking
For example, I have a route, I am heading somewhere and route updating while I am moving

I didn't find plugins like that for Leaflet (found only one which gets current location)

Is there a plugin to use a Leaflet as a GPS tracker?
Or another free online maps with such a function?

Thaaanks <3